# "He got the teacher to check the paper." and "He got the teacher checking the paper." I cannot understand the difference in meanings

Tags: grammar, causatives

Could you please explain the difference in the use of causative constructions with infinitives and present participles for my examples?

- He got the teacher to check the paper.
- He got the teacher checking the paper.

Comment: In the first one, the teacher checked the paper, and now it's over. The second is continuous: the teacher is checking the paper until... when?

Comment: The second one is basically wrong.  It would have to be "He *has* got the teacher checking the paper."

Comment: To my ears, the second one could be correct, if very informal, in certain specific situations.  For example, "The teacher thought Student A's assignment was flawless, but a chance comment from Student B got the teacher checking the paper again."

Comment: As usual, ***got*** is somewhat "slangy" in this context. We're [much more likely](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=got+him+to+check%2Chad+him+check&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) to say *He **had** the teacher check the paper*. And that's Americans as well as Brits.